# MYSQL Database: How do I structure the database for multiple devices and multiple data?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have to create a large database. It will hold the data from 100+ devices which will continuously updating database. For every 10sec each device will update a row in database. Is it better to have a separate table for each device data or have data in the same table with id of device.

Question:
I want to understand if there will be a significant performance improvement in updating the database if I used separate table for every device?

I also want to understand if there will be performance improvement in retrieving the same data back from db. We will be querying database too for each 10sec for new row updated. And I am using MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'device'?

Comment: @nickhar Ipad, iphone, tablet, etc. (so I'd assume)

Comment: @Evan Yes, just clarifying. Your answer covers it!

Comment: if need be, you could partition your table based on device ID, which would effectively create "separate" internal databases. but just because you've got 100+ devices writing every 10 seconds doesn't mean much. that's still just 10 queries/sec, which is essentially NOTHING for a modern db/server.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for creating a separate table here. You can simply have a table called `device_data` which will hold the `id` of the device as a `foreign key` to the `device` table which has all of the devices listed.

This will also make your life *much* easier when it comes to querying the database as you won't need to get data from dozens of different tables, you will have all of the data right there in one common place.

A sample query might look like:

```
Select DD.device_name, DD.device_data From
device_data
INNER JOIN device D On
DD.id = D.id
```

Comment: I understand that but will the query performance improve if I use different tables?